# Create a tree of folders in the list instance of a document library

Tags: document-library, folder

I created a document library list (in visual studio) and I want to set a tree of folders in the list instance not programmatically but in the element.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native Sharepoint way to populate items in list instance is using construction ([more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms478860.aspx)):

```
<Data><Rows><Row><Field>
```

But it isn't fit for document library and adding folders.

Check [this post](http://www.notesfor.net/post/2009/02/16/Deploy-a-Custom-SPList-with-folders-from-onetxml.aspx) that describes how to implement custom solution that populates structure of folders from xml file.